# Inno Setup Check if Antivirus Software is Installed

Tags: inno-setup, antivirus

is there a way to check if Antivirus software is installed using Inno Setup?

Comment: do you want to check for particular antivirus or else any antivirus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AntiVirusProduct` WMI class, depending of the window version you must connect to the `root\SecurityCenter` or the `root\SecurityCenter2` namespace.

For more detail check this article 
[`Getting the installed Antivirus, AntiSpyware and Firewall software using Delphi and the WMI`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/getting-the-installed-antivirus-antispyware-and-firewall-software-using-delphi-and-the-wmi/)

Note  :  The `AntiVirusProduct` WMI class only is supported for Windows Desktops editions (Windows XP, Windows Vista, 7, 8).

Try this sample.

```
function IsAntivirusInstalled: Boolean;
var
    FSWbemLocator: Variant;
    FWMIService   : Variant;
    FWbemObjectSet: Variant;
    Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin 
    GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);    
    Result := false;
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WBEMScripting.SWBEMLocator');

    if (Version.Major = 5) and (Version.Minor = 1) then //Windows XP
      FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\SecurityCenter', '', '')
    else
    if (Version.Major = 6) then 
      FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\SecurityCenter2', '', '')
    else
    exit;

    FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT displayName FROM AntiVirusProduct');
    Result := (FWbemObjectSet.Count > 0);
    FWbemObjectSet := Unassigned;
    FWMIService := Unassigned;
    FSWbemLocator := Unassigned;
end;
```